# Connect to old mailaccount after domain transfer

Tags: email, domain, imap, pop3

A few days agoo we successfully launched a new website for a new client.
The client had allready a simple wordpress site hosted on one.com, so we had to request a domain transfer.

After the transfer, we noticed that the mailbox wasn't synced with the new mailbox on our server. We contacted our hosting supplier and they want to do it if we pay for it.
I'm sure the same thing will happen again in the future so I'd rather learn how to do it than pay for it every time.

I've read one possible way to sync the two mailboxes is by connecting to it in outlook and copy the folders and mails from one account to the other. But how aw I able to connect (with IMAP) to an allready transfered domain?

FYI: Accessing the email account using webmail is no problem

Comment: It's a trivial matter of conneting to the old IMAP server. If the name of the old IMAP server has been removed from DNS (due to intentional replacement of the record or carelessness in preserving the contents of DNS when the domain was transfered) then just use the IP address.

Comment: 1) A downvote without clarifying? "This question does not show any research effort, it is unclear or not useful".?? IMO this is usefull since I didn't found an answer by searching serverfault or Google.
2) @Celada Thx for pointing me to the ip adress it helped me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Celada hinting me to use the IP-address of the old host (which wasn't known by the previous webmaster) I decided to contact One.com live support to get an ip.

Final they gave me alternative url for the mailserver. With this I was able to connect to the old webhost.

```
//alternative IMAP Address shared through live chat
mailservice03.one.com
```